# Insulating slab and vinyl siding

Tags: insulation, slab, vinyl-siding

I have a really cold corner of my house in a duplex. Here are some shots from an infrared camera. I hope we can get this fixed without tearing down the siding or ripping out freshly installed kitchen cabinets. I had the contractor insulate the wall but it is still crazy drafty.

Any help appreciated!

[image: Kitchen floor/cabinets]
[image: Kitchen cabinets/back wall]
[image: Outside slab/kitchen side]
[[image: Outside wall, overall view[4]]
[image: Outside wall, siding temp]
[image: Outside wall, melting snow]
[image: Outside wall, slab temp]

Comment: More details of construction probably required for any good answers.  You imply there's a slab.  What insulation does it already have?  What kind of insulation is in the walls?  What floor do you have on the slab?
What are your air barriers (insulation isn't for fixing drafts)?  What are your blower door test results?  How old is the construction?  What kind of heat is in the house?

Comment: It looks like there is a bad leak at the bottom of the sideing, other than that it looks normal to me, I love my (flir pro). I would see how the sideing is attached and see if there is a way to seal that area. If on a slab not much else you can do. But check the electrical for the stove and plumbing for the sink these are areas that if not sealed could allow a cold draft that you have. If you find the leak at those locations a can of spray foam may be your friend (not in the outlet but around it)

Comment: Jean-Paul here are additional information for you:
I am assuming the wall has R-13 and have no clue about the floor as we have hardwood on top of ceramic tile in the kitchen. I have no clue about air barriers, I vaguely recall seeing a blue Styrofoam between the 2x4s and the siding. I did not get a blower door test, maybe something to consider. The house was built in 1986. Heat is forced air gas. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ed, that is what I am also speculating about the siding. Do you think that sealing the bottom of the siding with blue greatstuff expanding foam will be safe? I read there should be moisture drainage in the siding? How about placing unfaced polystyrene foam board underneath siding right against and all along that slab where it shows dark red?

Comment: Anyone else has any ideas?